# how to resize .wmf format graphs

Tags: r

I am using the code below to make a .wmf graph, however the size of the output is too large (about 4MB), is there a way I could reduce the size below 500KB?

```
win.metafile('graph.wmf',width=5, height=5)
lw <- loess(y ~ x,data=cov, degree=0, span=0.95)
plot(y ~ x, data=cov)
j <- order(cov$x)
lines(cov$x[j],lw$fitted[j],col="red",lwd=3)
dev.off()
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `cov`? (i.e. how many observations?)

Comment: @BenBolker it's about 15000*26

Comment: `wmk` files are vector graphics so they store data for every object plotted.  Perhaps consider a raster image like `png` That may have a smaller size at the cost of not being infinitely resizable.